# How to bind imported ObservableCollection of strings to ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf

example

```
class abc
{
 public ObservableCollection<string> Data { get; set; }

//data will be initialized in some functions
}
```

and `wpf` application

```
namespace WpfApplication
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    [Import(typeof(GateManager))]
    public abc _abc { get; set; }

   public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }
} 

public void OnImportsSatisfied()
    {
        var binding = new Binding
        {
            Source = _abc,
            Path = new PropertyPath("Data")
        };
       databox.SetBinding(ItemsControl.SourceProperty, binding);  
   //databox is name of the ItemControl like                                //<ItemsControl x:Name="databox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
   //   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     //        <DataTemplate>
              // <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               //    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
             //  </StackPanel>
         //  </DataTemplate>
      //</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  //</ItemsControl>      }

 }
}
```

Im trying to do like this but this is not working

Comment: WPF, i wnat to know how to bind it code behind

Comment: if you write code behind anyway you can set the ItemsSource directly. databox.ItemsSource = _abc.Data;  whats the matter of setting the binding in codebehind?

Comment: its not working and what should i set for TextBlosk in ItemsControl?

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<string> Data { get; set; }
```

in XAML,

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

You want to set the ItemSource to the instance of an ObservableCollection you created in the constructor:

```
YourItemsControL.ItemsSource  = Data ;
```

Comment: You have to set the DataContext , on navigated event.I modified the answer

Comment: No you cant set in the navigation event because observable collection is in some other class and which is imported in wpf plz see the question again and i can set the context only in onImportSatisfied()

Comment: I guess you are not following MVVM WAY, then do like the above!

Comment: No im following MVVM way, This thing works fine for textblock and all but only in case of Itemscontrol im not able to do it

Answer (score 0):

Add DataContext also

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel:ManageUserViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

in cs file :

```
private ObservableCollection<UserType> _listUserTypes = new ObservableCollection<UserType>();
            public ObservableCollection<UserType> UserTypes
            {
                set
                {
                    _listUserTypes = value;

                }
                get
                {
                    return _listUserTypes;
                }
            }
```

In Xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserTypes, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```